# How can I make a keystroke to delete contiguous whitespace in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, keyboard, editing

I would like to figure out a way to have key bindings in Xcode (or perhaps more generally, any Cocoa text editor) that will delete (to the left or right, depending on the key binding) contiguous whitespace without deleting any non-whitespace characters or newlines.

For a left-whitespace-delete, I see the logic as being:

> "If there is a non-whitespace-or-newline character immediately to the
>   left of the carat, do nothing, otherwise delete all contiguous
>   whitespace characters to the left of the carat, leaving the carat
>   immediately following the first non-whitespace-or-newline character to
>   the left."

Obviously, I would also like a congruent right-operating version as well.

In an ideal world, I would like a more complex/intelligent behavior with respect to newlines, (perhaps deleting contiguous lines containing nothing but whitespace) but I would settle for this simple one first.

I have QuicKeys, and I'm not afraid to use it. :) I would also be willing to write something myself, if anyone has any ideas on how one might patch such a behavior in at runtime -- It'd be super excellent for this behavior to work in all Cocoa text editors on my system.

I am **NOT** interested in running emacs, vi, vim, pico, nano, WordStar or any other text editor. If the solution can't work in Xcode4, it's not a solution for me.

Comment: +∞. Xcode desperately needs a way to create custom editing macros and map them to keystrokes.

Comment: +1 for WordStar. -1 for not wanting to use it.

Comment: XVim should soon become your best buddy. At least, it's mine already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with something that *sort of* works.

#### First the false starts...

I first considered making an InputManager but InputManagers appear to have been deprecated as of Snow Leopard (for good reason, I guess... they're a huge gaping security hole) so they weren't an option.

I also looked at using [Input Method Kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/InputMethodKitFrameworkRef/_index.html). It's probably possible to do what I want using an Input Method, but then I'm stuck using a non-standard Input Method, which is sorta not what I want. As best I can tell, Input Methods aren't really the right tool for this job.

#### ...and then for the thing that (sort of) works.

It turns out that the Cocoa Text Editing key bindings system is quite configurable. I happened upon [this web page](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/%7Ejrus/Site/Cocoa%20Text%20System.html) that provided a great introduction. In short, I put a plist called DefaultKeyBinding.dict in ~/Library/KeyBindings/ that describes a couple of shortcuts.  Here's the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>@~^</key>
    <array>
        <string>setMark:</string>
        <string>moveWordForward:</string>
        <string>moveWordBackward:</string>
        <string>deleteToMark:</string>
    </array>
    <key>@~^$</key>
    <array>
        <string>setMark:</string>
        <string>moveWordBackward:</string>
        <string>moveWordForward:</string>
        <string>deleteToMark:</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The exact syntax/content of the key combos was derived from the aforementioned web page, but the net effect is that pressing Cmd-Opt-Ctrl-Delete sets the mark, moves forward one word (including all the whitespace prior to the word), then moves back one word (note that this is not the opposite of moving forward one word because it doesn't go back over the whitespace), and then deletes to the mark.  This is the equivalent of Shift-Opt-Right, Shift-Opt-Left, Delete.  The other key combo is the same, except that it adds shift, and reverses the behavior.

This isn't perfect, because it's not context aware. If you're not in a run of whitespace when you invoke it, you end up deleting a portion of the word you're in. That said, it's the best thing I've come up with in the year (plus) since I posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

I know one solution not as fast as using a macros, but not everyone can write a macros.

1. Choose the file that you need to get rid of the space.
2. Select text (most likely it is all of the text in the file.)
3. You press "Command + [", so all of the text to the left shift and space disappear. Probably will have to press the key combination several times, depending on the text formatting.
4. Now it remains to return the formatting for text blocks. Select the text and press the key combination "Command + ]". XCode will use tabs for indenting.

In the setting of XCode should be enabled Prefer indent using: Tab.